# Grails 1.3.5 controller test nulls command object

Tags: unit-testing, grails, controller, command-objects

Straight from page 104 of "The Definitive Guide to Grails (Second Edition)":

```
void testLoginUserNotFound() {
    mockRequest.method = "POST"
    mockDomain(User)
    MockUtils.prepareForConstraintsTests(LoginCommand)
    def cmd = new LoginCommand(login:"fred", password:"letmein")

    cmd.validate()
    controller.login(cmd)

    assertTrue cmd.hasErrors()
    assertEquals "user.not.found", cmd.errors.login
    assertEquals "/store/index", renderArgs.view
}
```

When this test is run, it fails with:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: null
```

...which I tracked down to the "cmd" reference being null at that point. Before the action controller.login is called, cmd is valid and filled, afterwards, it is null.

How can I test command objects?

Comment: [-1] I was right in part (**cmd is not null**), and partially wrong in other parts. - Nevertheless, I've identified, downloaded and corrected the samples so that they would **work** in practical unit test cases. - I'd expected some engagement and a resulting response. - Question abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

**`cmd` is not `null`**; however, `assertTrue` throws an `AssertionFailedError` with a `null` message. Either provide a default message (`assertTrue "default message", cmd.hasErrors()`) or just state, `assert cmd.hasErrors()`.

So, let's see why `cmd.hasErrors()` returns `false`. - That's because the custom validator does not return `false`, but some string instead, that evaluates to `true` according to the "Groovy Truth". (There, the Grails API appears to have changed since the book has been published.)

In the `LoginCommand` class, change

```
login blank:false, validator:{ val, cmd ->
    if(!cmd.user)
        return "user.not.found"
}
```

to

```
login blank:false, validator:{ val, cmd ->
    if(!cmd.user)
        return false
}
```

Then, the error code will be "LoginCommand.login.validator".
If you need a custom error code, you can [add an error object](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/AbstractErrors.html) yourself (without returning anything), like so:

```
login blank:false, validator:{ val, cmd ->
    if(!cmd.user)
        cmd.errors.rejectValue('login', 'user.not.found')
}
```

P.S.: You [shouldn't use](http://markmail.org/message/o6iwawbq4ouxtztw) the `MockUtils` class, directly, but instead `extend GrailsUnitTest`. Also, `MockUtils.prepareForConstraintsTests(Class)` is deprecated; moreover, it doesn't suit well for command objects. - Use the `mockForConstraintsTests(Class)` method instead, inherited from `GrailsUnitTest`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method in controller unit tests to add extra plumbing for command objects:

```
  private def invoke(String action) {
    def types = controller."$action".parameterTypes
    if (types && types.length == 1) {
      Class cmdClass = types[0]
      mockCommandObject(cmdClass)
      def cmd = cmdClass.newInstance()
      controller.params.each{ key, value ->
        try{ cmd."$key" = value } catch(MissingPropertyException ex){}
      }
      cmd.validate()
      controller."$action"(cmd)
    } else {
      controller."$action"()
    }
  }
```

The test looks like this:

```
    setup:
    controller.params.contractNum = "invalid"


    when:
    invoke "lookup"
```